# How to test if column names of multiple dataframes are same

Tags: r

Say I have 10 dataframes. I would like to check if all have same column names irrespective of their cases.
I can do this in multiple steps, but I was wondering if there is a shortcut way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, get the column names, convert it to a single case, get the `unique` and check if the `length` is 1

```
length(unique(lapply(lst1, function(x) sort(toupper(names(x)))))) == 1
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reduce` + `intersect` to get all the common column names in the list of dataframes and compare it with the names of any single dataframe in the list.

```
all(sort(Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, names))) == sort(names(list_df[[1]])))
```