# How create a list of unique column names from all dataframes [R]?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dozens of csv files/dataframes in a folder. Many dataframes have unique column names, and column names are out of order. I need to reorganize the column names, and eventually merge all dataframes. First, I want to create a list of all unique column names among all data frames. I can do it manually:

```
setwd(workingDir)

DRP003667 <- read.csv('DRP003667.csv')
DRP003669 <- read.csv('DRP003669.csv')

DRP003667_ls <- colnames(DRP003667)
DRP003669_ls <- colnames(DRP003669)

myls <- unique(c(DRP003667_ls,DRP003669_ls))

myls
[1] "ID"       "Time"         "Date"         "Length"         "Width"
```

How can I make this more efficient?

How do I open all csv files from a folder? How do I pull the column names from all files?

Comment: If you have a list of all the paths, it should be easy enough / maybe a better workflow to iterate along those paths to read the files from the start, then get the column names, then collapse those into a single vector

Comment: Also seems very related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/64271329/5325862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may get the datasets in a `list` from the object names created in the global environment using `mget` and use `lapply` to loop over the list, extract the column names, `unlist` the `list` and get the `unique`

```
unique(unlist(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^DRP\\d+")), names))
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what `mget` is doing here?